# How can I get actual dates to sync properly from SharePoint task list to MS Project?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync, ms-project

We have a Project File that we have synced to SharePoint 0365.

We want the team members to only update the Actual Start Dates in SharePoint to sync up to the Project File, which only the PM has access to.

When syncing the files and adding Actual Start Date, we received the following message: "The value of the following fields are dependent on each other in Microsoft Project.  In order to maintain the dependency, on the last field (Start) will be synched between SharePoint and Microsoft Project. The other fields (Actual Start) will have their value controlled by the value for Start"

What we are finding is:

If a user adds a date to Actual Start Date, the Project sync automatically overrides the SharePoint field to the Start date that is set in Project.

If a user changes the Start Date and not the Actual Date, then the Project sync automatically overrides the SharePoint field to the Baseline Start Date.